# Dynamically import Python module with Windows and Linux

Tags: python, import-module

I'm trying to dynamically import a Python module using `importlib`.

My project is an Azure function app and has the following file structure:

```
Shared_Code/
├── __init__.py
├── model.py
└── rule_engine.py
```

In the file `rule_engine.py` I'm trying to import `model.py`:

```
logging.info(__name__)
importlib.import_module(
    'Shared_Code.model', package=None
)
```

The above code prints

```
__app__.Shared_Code.rule_engine.py
```

and imports the module correctly on **Linux** and **Azure Cloud**.

However, when executing the exact same code on **Windows** I get an error that the module `Shared_Code` could not be found.

I've then used the following

```
importlib.import_module(
    '__app__.Shared_Code.model', package=None
)
```

which works on both, but breaks when running it on **Azure Cloud**.

Is there a generic solution for this without having to perform manual checks and if-clauses depending on the OS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to import `model` using a relative path:

```py
importlib.import_module('.model', package='Shared_Code')
```

**Edit**: After some research, I'm concluding that this is an Azure issue, not a Python one.

There isn't a *single* coincidence of the string `__app__` in the full [CPython code](https://github.com/python/cpython/).

There is, however, [this azure-functions-python-worker PR](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-python-worker/pull/325) where the `__app__` top-level module is implemented for absolute imports.

I guess this is a bug in azure-functions-python-worker, or whatever Azure platform you're working on, where they have different behavior between Linux and Azure Cloud VS Windows.

The only things I can think you can do are:

- See if there is some configuration in your Azure service, maybe in Windows is something different by default (I don't work with Azure platform, sorry).
- Fill an issue in [azure-functions-python-worker](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-python-worker), trying to include a minimal reproducible example, and see what they think about (maybe they have the answer, maybe you found a bug).
- The Pythonic solution: import the module without `__app__` inside a `try/except ModuleNotFoundError`, and if it fails import it again with `__app__`:

```py
try:
    importlib.import_module(
        'Shared_Code.model', package=None
    )
except ModuleNotFoundError:
    # In Windows, __app__ is mandatory
    importlib.import_module(
        '__app__.Shared_Code.model', package=None
    )
```

I know this last one is exactly what you're asking for *not* to do, but if it's a platform problem (and I'm pretty sure it is) there is nothing more you can do except to deal with it.

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't work. On Windows it riases a `Exception: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Shared_Code'`

Comment: @wasp256 I've updated my answer after looking more into the issue, that's all I can find about your problem, hope that helps you.